# IBM R61 Configured with Unity 16.04 & 2GB RAM

Tags: unity, 16.04

I have configured an IBM R61 with 2GB of RAM for a 10 year old and plan to upgrade the HDD to a SSD at Christmas.  Laptop mission includes

- Web browsing \ youtube
- Intro to Python
- Intro to Word Processing and spreadsheets

All 3 functions seem to work with good \ reasonable celerity.  Is there any practical consideration that has been overlooked that would require an upgrade to 3 or 4GB (Maximum)?

If you are running the same configuration please comment on any relevant observations: thank you.

Interesting note: although the crucial.com indicates a 4GB maximum there are [postings indicate it may be possible out with 8GB](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T61-and-prior-T-series/T61-and-8GB-ram/td-p/103294).

Answer (score 1):

No. 2GB of RAM is all your 10-year-old should need unless he starts gaming or programming intensively.

Even games such as Minecraft should run perfectly fine on the C61's CPU/GPU.